# Convert Byte Literals to Raw Literals

Tags: json, python-3.x

Is there a way in Python 3.5 to convert bytes literals to raw literals?

I need to parse json objects that I read from a file as byte literals they look like this:

```
#in the file they look like this: 
{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"abc=\"d\""}
#when they are loaded they look like this:
json_bytes = b'{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"abc="d""}'
```

Now if I `.decode('utf8')` them and load them with `json.loads()` it fails because in this case the double quotes are no longer escaped. Can i somehow either load them as raw string or convert the bytes literal into a raw string ?

Answer (score 0):

I now found the mistake. It seems it was a bug in the warcio library I use to parse WAT files. Updated to warcio 1.5 now everything works fine.